# 'otherwise' vs 'or else'

Tags: difference, parts-of-speech

> [otherwise](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/otherwise) = (adverb)
>   1. In circumstances different from those present or considered; or else:
>
> [or else](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/or-else?q=or+else) = (What part of speech???) 1.1. In circumstances different from those mentioned:

Does the semicolon definition 1 for 'otherwise' imply that these two are synonyms? What are the similarities and differences? Also, what part of speech?

Comment: *Or else* is two words.  It doesn't have a part of speech.

Comment: Isn't `or else` a compound word?

Comment: @Realdeo No. It’s really two words. It would even be wrong to hyphenate them.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, they're synonyms.

**Or else** is two words, so it’s not a part of speech. **Or** is a conjunction, which introduces a coordinate phrase or clause, meaning that the next phrase/clause is an alternative to the previous one. **Else** is an adjective or adverb, which means “in addition to what has been covered or seen so far.” Though its meaning is the same as **otherwise**, **else** is much more limited syntactically (see below).

**Otherwise** can serve as adverb or as a combined conjunction and adverb, meaning the same as **or else**. **Otherwise** usually doesn’t serve as an adjective, though I suppose you could force it into that role.

(Of course, since this is English, a very phrase-oriented language, I suppose you *could* say that **or else** is a phrasal conjunction. Most grammarians would disagree, and I’m hiding this remark inside parentheses, but I think it’s a reasonable idea.)

### Examples of *else*

> Is there someone **else** up there we could talk to? [[Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=6oVZAAAAMAAJ&q=monty+python+%22is+there+someone+else+up+there+we+could+talk+to%22). The speaker was displeased with the person who greeted him at a castle, so he asked to talk to **someone else**.]

There, **else** is an adjective modifying **someone**.

> You must find her attractive, or **else** you wouldn’t be talking about her so much.

There, **else** is an adverb modifying the clause **you wouldn’t be talking about her so much**.

You really don’t need **else** after **or**, because **or** means that the upcoming phrase or clause is an *additional* alternative to what has come before:

> You must find her attractive **or** you wouldn’t be talking about her so much.

The reason for saying **or else** instead of just **or** is partly to get the emphasis that comes from two words instead of one, sometimes maybe to get a nicer rhythm, but mainly because English is somewhat phrase-oriented (as I was saying in parentheses above) and listeners tend to perceive **or else** as a single unit of meaning (which would make it a two-word conjunction, but this is a decidedly nonstandard analysis).

You can also substitute **else** for **or else**, making **else** serve as a [conjunction](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/else#Conjunction), though I think this is mostly heard in British English:

> You must fancy her, **else** you wouldn’t be talking so much about her.

### Examples of *otherwise*

You can substitute **otherwise** in the previous example:

> You must fancy her, **otherwise** you wouldn’t be talking so much about her.

**Otherwise** can fit into many places where **else** won’t fit:

> **Otherwise**, the roof will collapse.
>
> You’ll have no alternative **otherwise**.
>
> Only a fool would do **otherwise**.

You could not substitute **else** for **otherwise** in those sentences, at least not in American English. **Else** as an adjective usually appears after the noun it modifies, and it’s usually a stock phrase like **someone else**, **anyone else**, **something else**, **anything else**, **what else**, **how else**, **or else**, etc. (Did I mention that English is somewhat phrase-oriented?)

### “Or else!”

**Or else** also has an idiomatic meaning when it’s not followed by a clause, like this:

> Pay up…or else.

This is what a gangster says to threaten someone with violence if they don’t do as the first part of the sentence says. It’s short for something like “Pay up, or else there will be consequences that you will find very unpleasant.” This usage of **or else** is somewhat ominous because the exact nature of the threat is unspecified.

Comment: Very comprehensive

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have a "part of speech", because it's 2 words not 1. In response to your comment, no, "or else" is not a compound word, which is a word made of 2 or more words (eg: pillowtalk).

You can use "otherwise" or "or else" interchangeably, they mean the same thing. It's worth noting that the use of "or else" can sometimes sound hostile due to its frequent usage in threats (eg: Do what I say or else...).

Answer (score -1):

Is this a map or a picture?
Is this a map or is this a picture?
Is this a map or else is this a picture?
You can't say: Is this a map or else a picture?
Soon after else you need to get full pattern with the verb part
or else it becomes clumsy looking.
Similarly otherwise takes the full pattern with the verb part.
or else and otherwise we are largely using as an alternative for if clause.