# "Else" or "otherwise"?

Tags: word-request

first of all, my native language is Spanish.

---

This is an example:

> If some result is incorrect, try contact with the page, else contact
>   with IRC

My question is if **else** is incorrect here? Is **otherwise** better?

Comment: Neither *else* nor *otherwise* sounds correct unless you mean *if the result is incorrect, contact me using that page. If the result is correct, contact me using IRC.* If you mean you can contact either using that page or using IRC, you can use either *either...or* or just *or*. Another problem is that *... try contact ...* expression is not correct. Either *try to contact* or *try contacting* will be fine.

Comment: Prayer becomes too long, I want a word like "else" or "otherwise", Is not posible these words?

Comment: @Man_From_India I think that both **else** and **otherwise** are correct,

Comment: @SamHarrington, So this is correct?: "If some result is incorrect, try contact to me, else contact with IRC"

Comment: **Else** means instead or in addition, and both of those could work here, (with slight change of grammar formatting.) Otherwise is very similar to else, so would have similar results.

Comment: @SamHarrington I think both are possible, but meaning will change.

Comment: @SinNombreSinApellido it is correct, but I think there are better ways of saying that phrase.

Comment: @SamHarrington Can you help me with the correct phrase?

Comment: hopefully the answer will cover that, and the difference between the two words.

Comment: Well, you could try switching the word **with** to **the** and then adding the word **or** before **else**.

Comment: @SamHarrington Thanks bro, so, this sound good?: "If some result is incorrect, try to contact "SinNombre", or else try read the wiki".

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33440/otherwise-vs-or-else)?

Comment: @SinNombreSinApellido that sounds great! but say '...or else try read(**ing**) the wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is if else is incorrect here? Is otherwise better?

In your original, you potentially have two things that either *else* or *otherwise* could switch on. The first is the *if* condition (i.e. *some result is incorrect*), and the second is the implicit condition that contacting (someone) via the page fails. Since it doesn't seem to make sense to have separate channels for communicating success and failure, the sentence parses with *else* switching on the implicit condition.

On the other hand, *if ... else ...* is a strong idiom in English, so it biases the reader to switch on the *if* condition.

Using *otherwise* in place of *else* doesn't help here. Doing so with your original sentence tends to break the sentence into two independent clauses:

- If the result is incorrect, try to contact the developer via the appropriate form on the page. Otherwise, contact the developer using IRC.

This seems to say that if the result *is* correct, the reader should contact the developer using IRC.

If I've understood your intent correctly, you're providing two means of contact in case one means fails. In that case, try the following:

- If the result is incorrect, please contact the developer using the details on the page or via IRC.

This lumps the alternatives together, avoiding the 'if/else switching' problem altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Your original sentence is hard to evaluate because it reads awkwardly. Also, there is no context to tell what you mean be "page" and "IRC".

I'll construct a similar example:

> If they have no black raspberry ice cream, try buying cherry vanilla. Otherwise, just get some strawberry.

I wouldn't use *else* in place of *otherwise* in this context. It wouldn't be grammatically wrong, but I think *otherwise* sounds a lot more natural.

By the way, I agree with Lawrence's point: the sentence might sound even better if you put the two "alternatives" together:

> If they have no black raspberry ice cream, try buying some cherry vanilla or  some strawberry.

That reads a little nicer; however, it's also less specific. It fails to clearly convey how cherry vanilla is a clear second choice, with strawberry as the third choice.

In formal writing, you could use the expression [*failing that*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/failing-that):

> If they have no black raspberry ice cream, try buying some cherry vanilla. Failing that, buy strawberry.